# jQuery UI Sortable - reference to cloned item in recieve event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-accordion

Here is the thing ... http://jsfiddle.net/2hJdL/.
Works pretty good, but i have problem with identification of selected fields. As you can see, i'm setting it by data() function to original object created in accordion. But when element is moved to sortable list, it's cloned without that identification.

In "receive" event i am disabling original element in accordion, so it can be dragged just once. But i cannot get reference to newly created item in sortable list and "data" is not cloned, so identification is lost. In addition, i need to store reference to original element, so when it's dragged back to accordion, i can reenable it.

Can somebody help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather hacky way to do it, but it's the only way I can fathom:

in your receive function:

```
$('.selector').sortable({
  receive: function(e, ui) {
    var newItem = $(this).data().sortable.currentItem;
  }
});
```

Comment: Not working anymore as of jquery UI v1.11.0.... I would like to see how I get the currentItem now (it has become an anonymous function)